# OpenGL Fragment Shader Return Fixed Color for Texture

Tags: opengl, shader, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader

I have the below fragment shader which currently returns the color of a pixel from texture:

```
varying vec2      v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D s_texture;
uniform vec4      vColor4;

void main()
{
  gl_FragColor = texture2D( s_texture, v_texCoord );
  //gl_FragColor = vColor4;
}
```

How do I change the fragment shader so that it returns a fixed color when a pixel is on and transparency when a pixel is off?

The TGA file I'm using contains transparency but a green and brown image (its a basic tree image - green top, brown trunk). What I'm trying to do is render the shape of the tree in one particular color (like a silhouette) instead of green, brown and transparency. If I change gl_FragColor to a set color, then the image paints as a solid rectangle -not what I want.

Is it just a matter of assigning the fixed colour and using the alpha (.a?) value returned by texture2D perhaps?

The line below gives me a white silhouette but the alpha channel is ignored so I get a white tree in a black rectangle:

```
  gl_FragColor = texture2D( s_texture, v_texCoord ).aaaa;
```

UPDATE: I tried the following but it is still rendering a rectangle. It appears that the transparency isn't being loaded into my texture. It is transparent for sure with GIMP but transparency is rendering as white for me for some reason.

```
  vec4 tmpColor = texture2D( s_texture, v_texCoord );

  tmpColor.r = vColor4.r;
  tmpColor.g = vColor4.g;
  tmpColor.b = vColor4.b;

//  gl_FragColor = texture2D( s_texture, v_texCoord );
  //gl_FragColor = vColor4;
  gl_FragColor = tmpColor;
```

My LoadTexture() function uses the following parameters:

```
  glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
  glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, TexHandle ); // Set our Tex handle as current

  // Specify filtering and edge actions
  glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
  glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );

  glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
  glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );

  //glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE );

  glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA, Img.GetWidth(),Img.GetHeight(),0,
                 GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,Img.GetImg() );
```

Bits per pixel (BPP) is definitely 32 (R,G,B,A).

Comment: Do you have blending enabled (`glEnable(GL_BLEND)`)? What is your blending function (`glBlendEquation`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to enable blending and a blending function (possibly specificyand equation also using `glBlendEquation`).

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

A great tester to see different blending equation results is [here](http://www.andersriggelsen.dk/glblendfunc.php)

Comment: Wow! I honestly thought (and read somewhere) that I couldn't use glEnable(GL_BLEND) with shaders so I stayed away from those 2 functions. It worked perfectly in conjunction with the shader I provided in my 'update'. Thanks heaps! Answer accepted.

Comment: @SparkyNZ: The only form of blending that doesn't work with shaders would be between texture "stages". You have to implement multi-texture blend equations yourself, but nobody complains about that because it's much more powerful. All other blending remains fixed-function :-\